# Anchor in pulltab not working

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've got an interesting problem I can't seem to solve nor find an answer for either here or on the web. To get straight to my problem:

I'm implementing a pull-tab for my website to alert visitors of some information and a link I'd like them to see. Currently the pull-tab is working correctly but the problem lies with the anchor. When I click it, it does nothing yet when I right-click and open in a new tab, it goes to the desired URL.

I have the pull tab in a div with an absolute position so the tab sticks out of the left side of the screen. Here is my HTML and jQuery that I'm using to get this feature to work so far:

```
<div class="pop-out-notice">
    <div class="tab">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15px" height="100px">
            <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="15px" height="100px" fill="rgb(187, 187, 187)" stroke="none"></rect>
            <text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="-0" y="0" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" font-size="17" style="text-anchor: end; dominant-baseline: hanging; cursor: pointer;" transform="rotate(-90)" text-rendering="optimizeSpeed">
                Pull This Tab
            </text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>60 Second Survey!</h3>
        Take a minute to help us tailor the library's website to better meet your needs:<br><br>
        <a href="[link here]">Click Here</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pop-out-notice .tab').click(function(){
            var popOutWidth = $('.pop-out-notice').css('left');
            if(popOutWidth === '0px'){
                $('.pop-out-notice').toggle(function(){
                    $(this).animate({'left': '-225px'}, 1000);
                }, function(){});
            }else if(popOutWidth === '-225px'){
                $('.pop-out-notice').toggle(function(){
                    $(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000);
                }, function(){});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anyone has any suggestions for what the problem might be or any ways to clean up this code, I'd be more than happy to try it out.

Thanks for your time and any help/suggestions you can give me!

Comment: I've actually gotten around this problem by adding another jQuery call and directing the window location to the href of my anchor. But if anyone has any actual answers to my problem that stopped the anchor from working, I'd love to hear it. Thanks! Here is how I fixed my problem with a slight work-around: window.location = jQuery('.pop-out-notice .content a').attr('href'); - When the anchor is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing and further research. I've fixed both my problems in the above question. I've fixed the link problem and I've cleaned up the code so it's far simpler than it was before. Here are my changes that have answered my problem.

I switched my code from using the animate class and instead used the toggleClass class with a new CSS element that mimics what I needed from the animate. Here is my changed code:

jQuery changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pop-out-notice .tab').click(function(){
        $('.pop-out-notice').toggleClass('pop-out-toggle');
    });
});
```

CSS Additions:

```
.pop-out-notice{
    ...
    transition: 1.75s;
}
.pop-out-toggle{
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

I'm sure my initial, convoluted, code had a lot to do with all the errors and funky things going on with it. I hope this helps anyone else that stumbles upon similar situations.